# Last line of css-run gallery overlaps

Tags: css, gallery

I'm using the prefab gallery in WordPress. For some inexplicable reason, the last few images, regardless of how many images are in the row (2,3,4) end up overlapping.   I moved the sort order around, re-added, re-titled and re-captioned the images, played around with various css settings etc and nothing seems to affect them.  I went back to the original css that I started out with. The code on each image comes up identical but something is making these images climb over each other. http://martinezstudio.com/wp_studio/flatweave/  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
<a href="http://martinezstudio.com/wp_studio/flatweave/lluvia/'>Lluvia</a>
```

You are mixing single and double quotes.

As a side note: I do not think that the tags for your gallery are very semantic. Opening and closing a definition list for each gallery item is not correct in my opinion. I would just use a single definition list, but this is rather hard to style as you do not have references between `dd` and `dt`. Therefore a normal unordered list with some subelements should do the job fine.

Please [verify your markup](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://martinezstudio.com/wp_studio/flatweave/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) the next time. You would have probably found the error yourself.